# Update current and next row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with few fields like below

```
ID | OpeningBal | A | B | C | D | ClosingBal
```

Here opening balance of current day is the closing balance of previous day and closing balance is calculated with this formula

```
OpeningBal + A - B - (C + D) - C
```

but current data is wrong in this table because of wrong formula applied previously for Closing Balance. I have tried like looping through all the records of this table and update the closing balance to the actual value. I want to update the opening balance of next row with the closing balance of current row in this cursor but I don't have the ID of next row. Any thoughts?

Actual Result:

```
ID  OPBal  A   B  C  D  CLBal
1   0      80  4  6  0  90
2   90     8   6  0  0  104
5   104    5   4  0  9  122
7   122    10  3  5  0  140
```

expected result:

```
ID  OPBal  A   B  C  D  CLBal
1   0      80  4  6  0  64
2   64     46  6  0  0  104
5   104    5   4  0  9  96
7   96     10  3  5  0  93
```

Comment: what is the sql server version being used?

Comment: If you are using a cursor, save the Closing balance in a variable and when you go to the next row, use that saved closing balance to update the current Opening balance.

Comment: @WEI_DBA , if I'm updating all the rows this will work but skipping rows because the closing balance is equals to new calculated closing balance, will result in wrong update right.

Comment: what about LAG and LEAD. Can you give a sample dataset and expected output

Comment: You should probably explain what the "next row" means. Sample data and expected output would also be useful. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also, your database design seems horribly denormalized, which is probably the source of your issues.

Comment: "update .. next row .. but I don't have the ID of next row" Are raws ordered by id, or datetime may be? Anyway you need a column which defines the order. "next row" is undefined without explicit ORDER BY.

Comment: Please provide a sample of data you have - and sample of what you need. Also, show what have you tried.

Comment: @scsimon updated sample script with the question

Comment: Keppy, but what is considered the 'next row' please? If you cannot determine the next row you don't have a series of rows, they are therefore  a set of non relational rows.

Comment: @LogicalMan, see in my sample the closing balance of the current row is the opening balance of next row. so when we update the current row I want to update the next row opening balance too and I guess the LAG and LEAD works for me. Thanks.

Comment: 64 on row 1 should be 72, right?

Comment: @scsimon, sorry, i have updated the formula. Its 64 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I got the solution using LAG and I will modify this based on my requirements.

```
SELECT 
        ID,
        LAG(ClosingBalance,1,0.00)  OVER (ORDER BY ID) PrevClosingBalance,
        ClosingBalance
    FROM Table1  

UPDATE Table1
SET OpeningBalnace = @PrevClosingBalance
ClosingBalance = @PrevClosingBalance + A - B -(C+D)-C
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update tablename set openingbalance=a.clcurrentrow from
(select LAG(closingbalance) over (order by id) clcurrentrow  from tablename ) a
```

Comment: this is useful but not the answer. :)